# Implementation of Jaccard Distance metric in nltk.metrics.distance not consistent with the mathematical definition?

Tags: nltk

I was trying to complete an NLP assignment using the Jaccard Distance metric function `jaccard_distance()` built into `nltk.metrics.distance`, when I noticed that the results from it did not make sense in the context I would expect.

When I examined the implementation of `jaccard_distance()` in the [online source](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/metrics/distance.html#jaccard_distance), I noticed that it was not consistent with the [mathematical definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) for the Jaccard index.

Specifically, the implementation in `nltk` is:

```
return (len(label1.union(label2)) - len(label1.intersection(label2)))/len(label1.union(label2))
```

but according to the definition, the numerator term should only involve an intersection of the two sets, which means the correct implementation should be:

```
return len(label1.intersection(label2))/len(label1.union(label2))
```

when I wrote my own function using the latter, I indeed obtained correct answers to my assignment. For example, I was tasked to recommend a correct spelling suggestion for the misspelled word **cormulent**, from a comprehensive corpus of words (built in `nltk`), using Jaccard Distance on trigrams of the words.

When I used the `jaccard_distance()` from `nltk`, I instead obtained so many perfect matches (the result from the distance function was `1.0`) that just were nowhere near being correct.

When I used my own function the latter implementation, I was able to get a spelling recommendation of **corpulent**, at a Jaccard Distance of 0.4 from **cormulent**, a decent recommendation.

Could there be a bug with `jaccard_distance()` in `nltk`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are implementing the Jaccard *coefficient* whereas the library has the Jaccard *distance*. The coefficient tells how related two sets are (it is high when they are similar), whereas the distance does the opposite; it is low when they are similar. In fact, they are each other's complement, i.e. *d* = 1-*c* and *c* = 1-*d*.

This is also explained on the [Wikipedia article you linked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index#Similarity_of_asymmetric_binary_attributes):

> [image]

Note that from the definition follows that the distance between entirely unrelated sets is 1 (not ∞ as you may expect) which explains the many "perfect matches" with a distance measure of 1. A perfect match in fact has a distance of 0 (which only happens when the sets are identical).